# Haar classifiers for object with varied poses

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to perform image recognition of large birds, and since the camera is moving, my usual tactic of background removal and shape recognition won't be effective. Since all adult birds [of the species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada_goose) are remarkably similar in coloration, I was thinking that Haar classifiers may be effective, and [found some resources](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) to try and train my own classifier.

Negative images should be significantly larger than the positive images, and present similar environments but not contain the positive image. However, I haven't been able to find too many details on what makes for a good positive training image. I found some references to trying to keep a similar aspect ratio in all positive training images, but for something like a bird that can change dramatically in different poses (wings open, wings closed), is it crucial? Is it better to train multiple classifiers for each pose and orientation of the target to be recognized? Is it better to instead try to identify a subset of the object that is relatively consistent (like the bird's very distinctive black and white head)?

If I use a sub-feature like the head, does it matter if it is "mirrored" in some views?  Should I artificially make my positive images face the same direction, and when running the classifier on an image, run it twice, once mirrored?  What are the considerations made when designing the positive image set for a classifier?